# nvidia drivers with cuda crashed ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia

I installed nvidia drivers and cuda successfully previously but had to reinstall it again but ran into some issues.

I was able to ssh into my machine and work but when I came into office and rebooted the machine it stops on reboot with

```
lvmetad is not active yet; using direct activation during sysinit
```

and I cant enable networking in recovery mode to make fixes

Any suggestions are welcome